# Evento ao carregar a página no Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ux

Sou novo na programação e recentemente me deparei com um evento de carregamento em várias plataformas, alguns exemplos são: Youtube e Epic Games.
(Print do evento anexada)

O evento consiste em:
1 - Enquanto a página carrega o conteúdo é exibido somente em um tom de cor.
2 - Ao terminar de carregar é exibido o conteúdo.

Alguém pode me explicar melhor como funciona isso? E também se existe um termo.
Desde já agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucas, nesse caso os elementos finais (que são os após serem carregados) não estão ai ainda! Ele estão muito provavelmente sendo criados e chamados de uma API ainda.

Para melhorar a experiência do usuário e aumentar o tempo de resposta do primeiro conteúdo na sua tela, os desenvolvedores (principalmente os designers UX que pensaram nessa experiência) utilizaram a técnica dos elementos Skeleton loaders.

Skeleton loader são componentes que, visualmente, se assemelham ao conteúdo sendo carregado mas que em si não possuem nenhuma ação e nenhum conteúdo específico

(Para uma leitura mais aprofundada de exemplos e uso utilizando a biblioteca material-ui: https://material-ui.com/pt/components/skeleton/)

Um exemplo utilizando a ideia do youtube a partir do link acima

[image: exemplo de skeleton loader do youtube]

Comment: Entendi, muto obrigado.